# java swing jlist addListSelectionListener ListSelectionListener called twice

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have this bug, after populating the JList, I try to retrieve the value of the selected item. But when I am doing it, it is called twice.

Here is my code :

```
 public CaveAdventureUI(CaveGame game) {
    initComponents();
    playerCarryItemModel = new DefaultListModel();
    caveCarryItemModel = new DefaultListModel();
    this.caveGame = game;
    this.world = game.getCaveWorld();
    listSelectionModel = this.jListCaveCarryItems.getSelectionModel();
    listSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    this.listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener( new SharedListSelectionHandler());
    //for debug purpose,see the world grid in console
    game.drawCaves();
    //new JComboBox(Mood.values());
    createGridQuarePanels();
    //world.startGame(GameLevel.Beginner);
    update();
}


private class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)listSelectionEvent.getSource();
         if (!lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            Occupant opt = mapOccupants.get(Integer.toString(jListCaveCarryItems.getSelectedIndex()));
            System.out.println("selected index :" +jListCaveCarryItems.getSelectedIndex() +"[["+opt.getName()+"]]");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, when I am making selection on jList : jListCaveCarryItems, it triggers the SharedListSelectionHandler class. However, when I am clicking on the JList, it print out the selected value twice.

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2 `ListSelectionEvents` are dispatched when the `JList` is selected—one during and another after the selection event. From [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

> The isAdjusting flag is true if the user is still manipulating the selection, and false if the user has finished changing the selection.

Therefore, ensure that the `ListSelectionEvent` value is not adjusting.

```
public void valueChanged( ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent)  {  
  if ( !listSelectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting() && !lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {  
     Occupant opt = ...
     ...
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but listSelectionEvent.isValueAdjusting() is not working, it complains cannot find symbol

Comment: @Jeffrey The correct method is `getValueIsAdjusting()`. A quick look at the javadoc would have shown you that (or any decent IDE with autocompletion)